# Does naive bayes algorithm work for Big Data?

Tags: naivebayes, bigdata

It is known that naive Bayes works for larger datasets. But is it also true that it works for big data? If no can you suggest algorithms for big data?

Comment: This question is way too generic. What kind of big data are you talking about and what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I am talking about the data collected in manufacturing environment. I need an algorithm which works well with manufacturing environment big data.